# How to Catch StriptTimeOut in Asp.Net so I can restart or bail a loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timeout

I have a function which is quite intensive, running a loop on a series of data.

It's used extremely infrequently, but I need to be able to catch any TimeOut errors and schedule to restart.

Is there any way to do this?

Or do I just have to set `ScriptTimeout` to something silly?

Comment: Can you post a relevant code? And how is it being called?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what your doing or what your code looks like but here is an example of running something a max of 10 times while catching an error.  You should really do this only for certain errors, like your timeout error, not ALL of them, as shown here.

```
Dim bSuccess as boolean = false
Dim iLoop as byte = 0
do while not bSuccess
  iLoop += 1
  Try
    ..Your code/method here
    bSuccess = true
  Catch ex as Exception
    'Check for max number of retries
    If iloop >= 10 then
      ..What do you want to do, bSuccess = true, Exit Do, Exit Sub, Throw ex, etc
    End if
    'Check if certain type of error to get out of loop
  End Try
loop
```